Comic with a worm with a bandage at the end of the body
I suddenly remembered a comic that I read as a child, but I can't remember much.
I read the comic in Catalan, but I think it was a translation, so the comic should exist in other languages.
In the comic one of the characters is a worm, in Catalan they call it Gus, which makes me think they took the name from Spanish, since in Spanish "gusano" means worm, so Gus is a perfect name for a worm.
The worm lives in a red apple but goes missing for the whole comic and nobody knows where it is.
There's a fortune teller that has a young lady (not sure if this characters are humans or animals) and there's an empty old round bird jail with a broken swing.
Suddenly the bird jail makes some noises and the fortune teller uses it as a kind of Ouija to ask questions to spirits, which the jail replies with 1 noise for Yes and 2 noises for no.
at the end it's discovered that it was the missing worm, hiding under the jail and knocking it with the lower part of its body, which had a bandage.
It's not a comic for small children, but I'd say a comic for young adults.
